# fancybox - jsp not working

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancyform

How can I use fancybox to display popup form in jsp? I have used fancybox in my html and it works great; but I have a trouble to include it in my jsp.

I have make sure to include the fancybox library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="resouces/js/fancybox.js" />"></script>
```

and in the jsp body I have:

```
<a class="modal-popup" href="#modal-create-form"><span class="small-icons plus-icon"></span>New Form</a>    

<div id="modal-create-form" class="modal-inline">Create Form</div>
```

If I click on the link, the "Create Form" will display with my html, but not my jsp.

Comment: I have test is by doing something like: $('.modal-popup').click(function(){ alert("click"); }). So I believe it is.

Comment: if you are gonna be sure press `Ctrl + U` and see if the script src attr is not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are included `fancybox.js`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".modal-popup").fancybox({

   });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/STgGM/2970/)**

Comment: I have make sure to include the fancybox library by including my own js file within the same directory of fancybox, and I can call my js file with no problem but not with the fancybox. I have tried to use yours but it doesnt work

Comment: You can see in `DEMO` it work perfectly. So check your code again might be something missing.

Comment: I have downloaded the library again and it works perfect now. Thank you for the help